# When ./configure is given conflicting options, which wins?

Tags: gcc, configure, autotools

I'm building a cross-compiling gcc using [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org), and can supply some additional configuration options to the ./configure step without patching the buildroot sources. However, I want to override an option that the buildroot sources have already explicitly set. Specifically, the buildroot sources have:

```
$(GCC_SRC_DIR)/configure $(QUIET) \
--prefix=/usr \
...
--disable-__cxa_atexit \
...
$(EXTRA_GCC_CONFIG_OPTIONS)
```

And I'm hoping to put `--enable-__cxa_atexit` into `$EXTRA_GCC_CONFIG_OPTIONS` and have that be what's honored.

I'm guessing that if buildroot's makefile is well-designed enough, then this is in fact what will happen. But I'm trying to verify this is so (in documentation, not by trial and error) and am having trouble finding any specification of what happens when conflicting options are passed to a ./configure script.

Will all autotools-based configure scripts handle this the same way? Or might gcc handle it one way, and (for example) binutils handle it a different way?

I expect someone else on SO has had to track this down before me. But my google-fu and SO-fu aren't turning anything up.

Comment: `autoconf` is very flexible and incredibly abusable, and throughout the years thousands of developers have abused it horribly so that there is very little consistency in `configure` scripts.  Whatever behavior you might expect will not be seen in all generated `configure` scripts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant documentation is [How Configuration Should Work](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Configuration.html) from the GNU Coding Standards and [Running configure Scripts / Optional Features](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Optional-Features.html#Optional-Features) from the Autoconf manual.

They don't mention conflicting options, so we're left with inspecting the shell code in a generated `configure` script. A script that I made with Autoconf 2.69 simply processes `--enable-foo` and `--disable-foo` options in order and assigns to `enable_foo`, therefore the latter option simply wins.